# Evaluation of curve fitting

Tags: curve-fitting

I have 10 different curves, and the curves are on different ranges. For example, curve 1 has range [-1,1], curve 2 has range [-10,10], etc.

Now  based on my model, I get one estimated curve for each of the 10 curves, so that I can calculate the MSE for each of the 10 curves.

Now the problem comes. Since the curves are in different ranges, it is not fair to compare the MSE directly, right? So I wonder anyone has any idea on developing a new metric that can take into account the different ranges?

Comment: Do you mean the range of X, or the range of Y?

Comment: What is the purpose of comparing these "curves"? Indeed, could you explain what you mean by a "curve"?